# To open "Eclipse" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime

Tags: eclipse, osx-yosemite

Just installed a fresh version of Kepler 64bit "for Java Developers" on Yosemite, getting this error on first launch. Any thoughts on how to fix? Really do not want to downgrade my Java version!

Comment: This is probably more suited to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) than SO.

Comment: Disagree. Eclipse is an essential IDE for many software developers

Comment: Indeed, but this question isn't about programming per se - it's more about OSX system set-up, so the Ask Different users might have more insight into this.

Comment: They may, but this isn't about system setup. This is about setup of a developer tool. I don't want to change my system configuration. Questions about developer tools are explicitly on topic, on Stack Overflow, as outlined in the Stack Overflow help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Running the Java 8 JDK (rather than the JRE) worked for me but this does seem to vary a lot for different users.

Comment: How is it possible that in 2019 Eclipse still opens a Java 6 dialog instead of letting me use `.sdkman/candidates/java/current`. F*** salt

Comment: Java via SDKMAN! can be used by configuring eclipse.ini; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694738/186818

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up relenting and downloading Java 6 from here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Apparently this seems to coexist ok with the latest Java version which I also installed (version 8 update 25) and version 8 shows up as the version I'm running when I verify from

https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

I'm unclear on the security implications of this though, would have preferred another solution, if anyone finds a better solution than installing 6 please let me know.

Comment: OK, I did vote for this answer (which was a quick solution, and worked).  Seems like there has to be a better solution (than downloading 80MB of software that isn't used).  Thanks for links, etc.

Comment: 80MB of software isn't the problem, the problem is that Java 6 is [far past EOL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) and won't be receiving updates anymore.  It's a significant security hole on your system and any solution that involves installing Java 6 this late in the game must be the wrong one.

Comment: This got me part of the way there.  I then needed to go here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html.  For Mac I needed to download jdk-7u79-macosx-x64.dmg

Comment: The latest versions of Eclipse do not support Java 6

Answer (score 36):

I just encountered this in another Eclipse-based app on Yosemite and figured out (with help from the references below) how to get the app running **without** installing the legacy Java SE 6 JRE. Here are the steps in case it helps other devs get Eclipse working.

**PRECONDITIONS**

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion 
10.10.1
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

*Other configurations might work; this is my environment.*

**STEPS**

1. Edit the info.plist for the JDK after installing:

   ```
   $ sudo nano `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`/../info.plist
   ```
2. Change the following section:

   ```
   <key>JVMCapabilities</key>
    <array>
     <string>CommandLine</string>
    </array>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <key>JVMCapabilities</key>
    <array>
     <string>JNI</string>
     <string>BundledApp</string>
     <string>WebStart</string>
     <string>Applets</string>
     <string>CommandLine</string>
    </array>
   ```
3. Try to open the app from the command-line (not sure if this is strictly necessary, but what I did)

   You should get an error "(app) can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer."
4. Go to System Preferences: Security Settings (General) and you should see the recent app next to a button "Open Anyway" -- click this button to open the app.

This opens Eclipse without requiring the separate download of the legacy Java SE 6 files.

**NOTES**

When I was solving this on MTGBrowser (below) I also followed advice to change the info.plist of the app by adding the following section to the 'Eclipse' key:

```
<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

However, I'm not sure that's strictly required.  In any case, that wasn't sufficient -- I also had to change the JDK info.plist and security as described above for a complete solution.

**REFERENCES**

- https://sourceforge.net/p/mtgbrowser/bugs/402/#c78c
- http://crunchify.com/os-x-mavericks-eclipse-java-issue/
- http://mac-how-to.wonderhowto.com/how-to/open-third-party-apps-from-unidentified-developers-mac-os-x-0158095/

Comment: This is the best answer. Also, confirmed that you don't need to add anything to the Eclipse key as mentioned in the "NOTES" section.

Comment: I removed the -V from the java_home command because it printed a lot of extra lines.  The Installer launched without requesting Java 6. But then it threw a NullPointerException and then hung.

Answer (score 31):

I was facing this trouble for hours. I followed every suggestion I could find over numerous forums with no success. I resolved the issue by simply installing 1.8.x JDK instead of the JRE, despite having no intension to develop for Java. I guess eclipse requires this.

Comment: Given that it's a Java IDE intended originally to develop in Java, that's not much of a stretch.

Comment: Worked for me! I didn't want to install the legacy Java 6 or manually mess with configuration files so this was the best solution, even though I don't intend to develop in Java either.

Comment: Actually, you will get to this answer as soon as you do `java -version` according to Larry Kyrala's answer and realise you have to install the JDK (at least I got the message). So thanks to both Larry and Daniel :-).

Comment: I'm getting the above issue on Yosemite with java version "1.7.0_45" - so why is it the case that Yosemite/Eclipse needs java 6 or 8, but not 7?

Answer (score 5):

**tldr;** This error may indicate you don't have Java, and you can fix by installing the latest version of Java instead of the "legacy" version

---

I received this error while installing Eclipse on a fresh MacBook with macOS Sierra, version 10.12.3, which apparently does not have ANY java installed.  I made the problem go away by installing java version 1.8 JDK and then had no trouble installing Eclipse after.

i.e. before installing

```
MacBook-Pro:$ java -version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

and after installing

```
MacBook-Pro:$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Installing latest JDK works. Confirming with JDK 10.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

My Mac crashed and after the restart I had the same issue. Turned out that for some reason the file `/usr/libexec/java_home` was missing. After symlinking it to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home`, Eclipse now starts without any complains.

Answer (score 0):

I had JDK 7 installed on Yosemite, and upgrading Eclipse to `Luna` fixed this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked :

Edit /Applications/mat.app/Contents/Info.plist

And at he bottom where the to use a specific Java version section start you reference the libjli.dylib like so

```
<string>-vm</string><string>/Users/jkuperus/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open//lib/jli/libjli.dylib</string>
```