# Eclipse can't find jdk installed with sdkman

Tags: eclipse, java-home, sdkman

Im new with sdkman, but I managed to install it and install some software with it: JDK, Gradle and a few others. The problem is that after I downloaded Eclipse and tried to run it, it just simply can't find the JDK. I have already exported JAVA_HOME, and PATH. In fact, I can actually run java, javac and other Java commands from the terminal, I even tried with update-alternatives. I have changed the ownership of the eclipse folder with no results, Eclipse cannot find the JDK.

I had to install java with apt-get and that makes eclipse work, but whats the of using sdkman? So my question is: What configuration am I missing to make Eclipse use the sdkman java installation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by creating a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` for both java and javac.

```
sudo ln -s ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac
sudo ln -s ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

I got these locations by doing

```
which javac
which java
```

Comment: Isn't there a better solution for this?

Comment: I am still facing the same issue on macos-mojave - I posted a new question for it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686052/sdkman-does-not-work-with-eclipse-app-or-springtoolsuite4-app-on-mac

Comment: when I execute the command above, as superuser, it says "Operation not permitted"

Comment: $JAVA_HOME still points towards old version (installed with update-alternatives), though `java` and `javac` point towards SDKMAN! candidate now. What can I do to let $JAVA_HOME point towards my SDKMAN! candidate?

Comment: This solution work for me while using `dbeaver` with `sdkman`. I am adding this comment because I didn't know where to add absolute path in this given solution - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014157/dbeaver-with-sdkman-jre-jdk-location. So I have used this one for temporary just work solution.

Answer (score 4):

Locate and edit your eclipse.ini file and change the line right after "-vm" to this:

```
/home/YOURUSER/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin
```

That should do it for Linux systems. I'm not sure about Windows or Mac tho.

Comment: Great thanks! note for me path was : /Users/YOURUSER/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin

Answer (score 0):

### macOS

For macOS you need to set (or add) the `-vm` argument to your `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`, for example:

```
-vm
/Users/<YOUR_USER>/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.272.hs-adpt/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib
```

This is now included (somewhat non-obviously) in the eclipse.ini documentation: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Using_a_JDK_without_macOS_directory_layout

> **NOTE:** Beware that if you use `current` instead of using a specific JDK version identifier it will use the default if you launch the Eclipse.app using the UI (double-click or using Spotlight). If you launch it from a terminal it will use the one currently selected.