# To open “STS” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

I've just downloaded the latest version of **Spring Tool Suite** (`v3.9.5`) for MacOS (High Sierra v.10.13.2) and when running STS I'm getting this error:
`To open “STS” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.`

When I checked what version of Java is installed with on my mac I get:

```
$ java --version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

Similar issues with Eclipse and older MacOS versions:

[To open "Eclipse" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847411/to-open-eclipse-you-need-to-install-the-legacy-java-se-6-runtime)

Bug in Eclipse:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't download old legacy Java**

Go to Oracle and install the **latest JDK**.

Verify in Termial:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

STS will start now.